# ¿Como puedo mostrar una relación de Mongo (populate) en una tabla de angular?

Tags: array, angular, typescript, objeto, ngfor

Estoy tratando de mostrar datos de dos colecciones mediante la función populate de Mongoose en una tabla de angular pero no logro mostrar el usuario de manera correcta

Al realizar la petición y mostrar los datos con angular lo hace de manera correcta excepto del registerUser.user

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado de mostrar los datos de la tabla es el siguiente,dandome el error de

> [object,Object]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que uso en mi servicio para mandar a llamar la petición get de mi app

```
 cargarCategoria(pagination:number=0){
    const url = `${base_url}/category/get-categorys?pagination=${pagination}`;
    return this.http.get<CargarCategoria>(url, this.headers)
  .pipe(
    map(resp=>{
      const categorias=resp.allCategorys
        console.log(categorias)
        return{
          total:resp.total,
          categorias
        }
      
    })
    
  );
}
```

Por otro lado tengo el código de mi componente.ts

```
cargarCategorias(){
  this.cargando=true;
  this.categoriaService.cargarCategoria(this.pagination)
  .subscribe(({total,categorias})=>{
    this.cargando=false;
   this.categorias=categorias
   this.totalCategorias=total
   console.log(this.totalCategorias);
   console.log(this.categorias)
  })
}
```

Y finalmente tengo el ngFor de mi html que me muestra los datos

```
<tr *ngFor="let categoria of categorias">
  <td class="w100-c">{{categoria._id}}</td>
  <td class="w180" ><input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Nombre de la categoria" 
                    [(ngModel)]="categoria.name"></td>
  <td class="w100-c">{{categoria.registerUser}}</td>
```

Intente agregando el categoria.registerUser.user pero me da un error

> Object is possibly 'undefined'

He pensado en extraer el id de la propiedad registerUser y hacer otro ngFor donde mande a llamar todos los usuarios y imprimirlos en el lugar correspondiente pero no se como lograr extraer el id si no me permite extraer los datos de esa propiedad del registerUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador `?` para evitar el error:

```
td class="w100-c">{{categoria.registerUser?.user}}</td>
```

> ## [Operador de encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
>
> El operador de encadenamiento opcional `?.` permite leer el valor de una propiedad ubicada dentro de una cadena de objetos conectados sin tener que validar expresamente que cada referencia en la cadena sea válida. El operador `?`. funciona de manera similar a el operador de encadenamiento `.`, excepto que en lugar de causar un error si una referencia es casi-nula (`null` o `undefined`), la expresión hace una evaluación de circuito corto con un valor de retorno de undefined. Cuando se usa con llamadas a funciones, devuelve `undefined` si la función dada no existe.

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchas gracias, fue muy sencilla la solución no esperaba que fuera eso